# What are some ways to isolate a TTL serial GPS device from high frequency noise caused by a processor and other peripherals?

Tags: gps, emi-filtering

I'm trying to interface a GPS receiver with a Minnowboard Turbot Single Board Computer via a ttl serial UART on the boards expansion header but there is a substantial amount of noise on the UART and power pins coming from the Minnowboard and it is causing very low SNR values in the GPS device and the GPS never gets a fix.  Moving the GPS device or antenna further from the board doesn't work, the noise is being transmitted through the header pins themselves.

What kind of circuitry do I need[0] to build to isolate the GPS from the interference on those pins?

[image]

[0] I've already tried putting ferrite beads on all the connections tx, rx, pwr, gnd to the GPS but it didn't improve the situation enough to get a GPS lock.

Comment: Its hard to imagine the GPIO pins are injecting so much noise as to prevent locking. Have you double checked your grounding connections?

Comment: How do you know there's noise coming from the UART lines? UART works at a couple hundred kHz max, and GPS at around 1 GHz, so this is a pretty bold claim.

Comment: Some photos of the setup might help.

Comment: use two ground wires coming from as close as possible from the power supply, one ground wire goes to the computer/microcontroller, another one goes to the gps module.

Comment: I'm positive it is coming through the pins.  The processor runs at 1.46 Ghz and the USB3.0 also appears to add noise if I have a device plugged in.  I used a process of elimination leaving the GPS in the same spot relative to the board and connecting it to the pins on the header vs connecting it through a FTDI USB -> serial converter.  using the FTDI all the interference disappears and the GPS locks in less than 60 seconds.  If I use any of the pins on that header though SNR values are about 50% worse and it can sit all day w/o getting a fix.

Comment: @pipe you can see a picture of the board I'm using on the project's website, https://www.minnowboard.org/ I have 3.3v power, GND, TX and RX connected to the GPS device coming off that 28 pin 0.1 inch pitch header in the bottom left corner of the board.  I've tried multiple GPS devices they all have the same problem when connected any of the pins on that header.

Comment: @Pete Actually I can't see a picture because the whole website seems to be wrapped in one big chunk of javascript, but maybe you can add a picture to the question for everyone to read?

Comment: @pipe ok, I've take then photo from the site and added it to the question.

Comment: If we forget about my specific case for a minute what are methods to isolate a device from noise in the 1Ghz - 2Ghz range besides ferrite beads.

Comment: On what basis do you claim that the headers are producing 1-2Ghz noise. This is very unlikely. Have you probed the header pins? Can we see a scope shot?

Comment: @Adil Malik It is interfering with the GPS which operates around 1.5 Ghz.  I also attached the pins to a spectrum analyzer using a DC block and there were spikes in that range.  I also attached the GPS via a FTDI chip instead of to that header and the SNR values reported by the GPS were almost twice as good and it locked immediately.

Comment: Try powering the module from a battery, or something external. See if it works then.

Comment: @Adil Malik Yeah, I tried a separate power supply but that alone made no difference because interference was still coming in on the serial lines.  I need something to isolate the GPS from the EMI on that header.

Comment: Looking at the [schematics](http://wiki.minnowboard.org/images/b/bd/Minnowboard_Turbot_X205_Sch.pdf)(sheet 20&22), it is possible that 500kHz switching ripple from the [DC/DC-converter](http://www.monolithicpower.com/DesktopModules/DocumentManage/API/Document/getDocument?id=820) makes it to the [level shifter](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTS0104.pdf) and the pin header. Verify with a scope, counter-measures for 500kHz and 1.5GHz would be quite different.

Comment: Just as an idea, those IO lines are very slow, so you may be able to put bypass caps on the IO lines. If you try it, it will be important to place them very close to the GPS and minimize inductance (no wires). I am thinking 22 pF or so. You can experiment, but certainly no more than 100pF.  The cap may be operating above the SRF. That is OK, but choose one with the lowest impedance at 2GHz that you can find. A series R will help also. I believe SMT resistors still have good resistance at GHz.

Comment: Not clear from the question if you tried this yet, but it might help to put an external ferrite on the cable between the two devices. The ferrite selection will matter. Make sure it has high impedance at 1-2 GHz.

Comment: A single ferrite on a cable will work WAY better than individual chip bead ferrites on every line. My experience comes from trying to meet emissions standards rather than having interference. But it is the same problem, ultimately. Common mode RF noise.

Comment: When you ran the GPS off a FTDI did you have the Minnowboard running and in the same location relative to the GPS module? Also try connecting just the ground to the Minnowboard while running off the FTDI.

Comment: Yes, same separation and relative positioning for direct serial connection vs FTDI.  I ended up fixing this by using filters on each of the lines to the GPS module pwr, tx, rx.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - the issue would not typically be the UART signals, or even their edges, but rather that those conductors (including the signal grounds) come from a board chock full of radio frequency digital noise sources.  Hence it's typical for them to couple out interference even when the serial port is idle with no signaling in either direction.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yeah, I don't know why I wrote that back then.

Answer (score 1):

How high a resistance can you place in those UART lines? 1Kohms? 10Kohms?

Notice I've created a low-resistance (but not ZERO-resistance) ground path, at bottom of the schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgxvoW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>